# Find the customer name, customer street, customer city of the account which has the highest balance among all the accounts

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Tables of customer, account and depositor

[image: Tables of customer, account and depositor]

I have tried like this:

```
select customer_name, customer_city, customer_street, max(balance)
from customer
  natural join depositor
  natural join account;
```

But its showing me

```
Error: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

Comment: Hint: ORDER BY, FETCH FIRST.

Comment: I think you need to get the max balance first and then use that to find the customer. I don't do Oracle but if you show me the query in ANSI SQL I could show you how to make it work.

Comment: I don't know ANSI SQL. It might work with 'ALL'. But I don't know how to use it!

Comment: What is your Oracle version? If it's 12.1 or higher, the easiest answer is what jarlh suggested already: replace `max(balance)` with `balance`, and add `order by balance desc nulls last` and then use the `fetch ... ` clause. Separately, regardless of method, what is the requirement if two or more accounts are tied for "highest balance"? Show both (or all of them, if more than two)? Show just one of them - and if so, which one? Will "any of the tied accounts" work, it doesn't matter which one? In such problems, you must always think about - and address - ties for "best", "last", "highest" etc.